# Вывести html после 3-го </p>

Tags: php

есть код который выводит модуль (html) после первого `</p>`

```
<?php  
    //Полный текст материала
    $item_fulltext = $this->item->fulltext;
    //модуль, который необходимо вывести
    $shapeexpert_module = JHtml::_('content.prepare', '[module-246]'); 
    //находим первый закрывающий тег </p>
    $pos = strpos($item_fulltext,'</p>', 1); 
    //отделяем первый абзац от 0 до номера позиции.
    //Вставляем модуль, и вставим вторую половину текста.
    echo $result_text = substr($item_fulltext,0,$pos)  .  $shapeexpert_module .  substr($item_fulltext,$pos); 
?>
```

Как вывести модуль, скажем, после 3-го `</p>`. Благодарю!

Comment: какие есть мысли?

Comment: @Ипатьев к сожалению мысли только те, что изложил в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вопрос интересен и существует множество способов решения, довольно интересный способ с точки зрения написания кода - это проверка различного набора символов путем цикла, но это трудоемкий процесс, который потребует много ресурсов, что лишает этот вариант смысла, по крайней мере в реальном проекте, когда есть аналогичные решения не требующие большого объема вычислительной мощности.

В Вашем случаи идеально подойдет `documentElement`, нет - это не JS.

```
<?php
$pastText = 'Текст, который был вставлен после первого тега параграфа';

$html = <<<'EOD'
<h1>Вставляем текст после первого тега <p></p></h1>
<p>Первый тег параграфа</p>
<p>Второй тег параграфа</p>
<p>Третий тег параграфа</p>
EOD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $html . '</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$targetNode = $xp->query('//h1/following-sibling::p[2]');

if ($targetNode->length) {
    $targetNode = $targetNode->item(0);
    $newNode = $dom->createElement('div', $pastText);
    $targetNode->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $targetNode->nextSibling);
    $targetNode->parentNode->insertBefore($dom->createTextNode("\n"), $targetNode->nextSibling);
}

$result = '';
foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}
echo $result;
```

`$html` - наше тело страницы, как я полагаю вместо переменной `$html` вы можете вставить `$this->item->fulltext`

`$xp->query('//h1/following-sibling::p[2]')` с этой строчкой я думаю всё понятно, мы идем по структуре HTML документа, в моем случаи это html->p::2, то есть после второго тега параграфа будет вставлен нужный нам текст.

Comment: Это ОЧЕНЬ, ОЧЕНЬ, ОЧЕНЬ смешной ответ. Разумеется, в части "три строковых поиска положат нам сервер, и поэтому мы распарсим весь хтмл в дерево, то есть выполним на три порядка больше строковых операций и потратим на три порядка больше памяти, но поскольку мы всего этого не писали, то этого как бы и нет - значит мы сэкономили офигенную кучу ресурсов!"

Comment: Благодарю. Я думал что можно получить решение c помощью strpos. То есть получить второе или третье вхождение строки

Comment: @Ипатьев используя  $pos = strpos($item_fulltext,'</p>', strpos($item_fulltext,'</p>')+strlen('</p>')); можно в одну строку получить 2-ое вхождение :)

Comment: @Ivan можно. а еще существует такая вещь, как цикл